# Extracting the attribute from an XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, attributes

I am using the $(xml).find(); method to pull data from an XML file. However, from a different XML file, I would like to pull an attribute.
For example, here is a sample of the XML file:

```
 <members>
    <member>
        <statedistrict>AK00</statedistrict>
        <member-info>
            <namelist>Young, Don</namelist>
            <bioguideID>Y000033</bioguideID>
            <lastname>Young</lastname>
            <firstname>Don</firstname>
            <middlename/>
            <sort-name>YOUNG,DON</sort-name>
            <suffix/>
            <courtesy>Mr.</courtesy>
            <prior-congress>113</prior-congress>
            <official-name>Don Young</official-name>
            <formal-name>Mr. Young of Alaska</formal-name>
            <party>R</party>
            <caucus>R</caucus>
            <state postal-code="AK">
                <state-fullname>Alaska</state-fullname>
            </state>
            <district>At Large</district>
            <townname>Fort Yukon</townname>
            <office-building>RHOB</office-building>

        </committee-assignments>
```

How would I pull the postal code value "AK" rather than the state-fullname value Alaska?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get attributes from a tag

```
$(xml).find('state').attr('postal-code');
```